# C++ Eliminate functions and replace with constructors

Tags: c++

I just had my first class for constructors and destructors and didn't quite get how things work. I need to eliminate setWidth and setLength  functions of the Rectangle class and replace them with a constructor.  Can anyone help me, pls?!

Here is what I have so far:

```
class Rectangle {

public:
    Rectangle(double=1.0, double=1.0);  // Constructor
    double perimeter(void);
    double area(void);
    void   setWidth(double w);
    void   setLength(double l);
    double getWidth(void);
    double getLength(void);

private:
    double length;
    double width;
};
//   Constructor
Rectangle::Rectangle(double w, double l)
{
    setWidth(w);
    setLength(l);
}

double Rectangle::area(void)
{
    return length * width;
}

double Rectangle::perimeter(void)
{
    return 2*(length+width);
}

void Rectangle::setWidth(double w)
{
    if ( w> 0 && w < 20.0)
        width=w;
    else
        width=1.0;
}

void Rectangle::setLength(double l)
{
    length= l > 0 && l < 20.0 ? l : 1.0;
}

double Rectangle::getWidth(void)
{
    return width;
}

double Rectangle::getLength(void)
{
    return length;
}

int main()
{
    Rectangle R;
    R.setLength(5);
    R.setWidth(4);
    cout << R.area() << endl;
    cout << R.perimeter() << endl;

    Rectangle* pR = new Rectangle;
    pR -> setLength(10);
    pR -> setWidth(5);

    cout << pR->area() << endl;        // Call the area() function using pR
    cout << pR->perimeter() << endl;        // Call the perimeter() function using pR

    delete pR;

    }
```

Comment: Do you want those in the actual constructor initialization line (i.e an empty constructor body)? If so, its a little convoluted, but easily doable with a doubled-up ternary operator set. But I guess the thing I'm lost on is why you're not just using `Rectangle R(4.0,5.0);` in `main()` in the first place? You already have the constructor right there.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the assignment correctly you are supposed to change the code so that the code does not call `setLength` and `setWidth` directly. You already have the constructor defined, and all you need is to use it. The proper solution would be to replace this:

```
Rectangle R;
R.setLength(5);
R.setWidth(4);
```

with this:

```
Rectangle R(4, 5);
```

Also, to replace this:

```
Rectangle* pR = new Rectangle;
pR -> setLength(10);
pR -> setWidth(5);
```

with this:

```
Rectangle* pR = new Rectangle(5, 10);
```

The "trick" (for you, as a beginner) is to know why the order of parameters is (4, 5), and not (5, 4). If you know why, then the lesson is over.

Comment: The suggestion should be *"Replace this `Rectangle R` with this `Rectangle R(4,5);` and avoid `Rectangle* pR = new Rectangle;` and `Rectangle* pR = new Rectangle(5, 10);` completely"*

Comment: @Manu343726 I will assume that you are serious and that you are talking about coding style. OP is doing lessons and learning at the moment. The purpose of the code given to him is not to do something useful, but to make him learn current lesson. In this context it would be wrong to tell him to avoid creating objects on heap. That's not the focus of current lesson.

Comment: Of course my comment does not fit in the current OP lesson, but I think that avoiding bad coding practices since the beggining is good for his learning (Note that that wasn't a critic, I have upvoted your answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the values for the internal variables directly in a couple of ways from your constructor:

**Option #1**

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(double w, double l)
{
    width = w;
    length = l;
}
```

**Option #2**

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(double w, double l) :
   width(w),
   length(l)
{
}
```

NOTE:  If I recall correctly, the pointer to "this" does not exist until inside the constructor itself.  So if your Rectangle class was derived from a "Shape" class and you needed to initialize the Shape(...) constructor in the Rectangle constructor call (which you can do in Option #2, pass arguments to the base class constructor), don't pass in the "this" pointer from your rectangle instance; it is not defined yet.  For that, you will need a base class function like "set derived class pointer".  You probably should NOT be doing it anyway, but if you do, be careful.

e.g.

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(double w, double l) : 
length(w),
width(l),
Shape(this) // I don't believe you can do this.
{
}
```

Was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a possible requirement that the width and length must both be greater than 0 and less than 20; that's enforced in the setWidth and setLength member function. It's better style, though, to use the initializer list in the constructor. I'd add a function to limit the values to the required range, and use that in both the constructor and the setXXX functions:

```
class Rectangle {
public:
    Rectangle(double w, double l)
        : width(limit(w)), length(limit(l)) {
    }
    void setWidth(double w) {
        width = limit(w);
    }
    void setLength(double l) {
        length = limit(l);
    }
private:
    double limit(double value) { return 0 < value && value < 20 ? value : 1.0; }
};
```

Note that I also removed the default argument for the constructor. That's partly a matter of style: if there's a requirement for defaults of 1.0, put them back, but those values look pretty arbitrary to me. Similarly, the 1.0 in `limit` looks arbitrary; if there's a requirement that the values be in range, it's probably more appropriate to throw an exception if they're not.

Comment: First, requirements are actually enforced in constructor, because setters are used there. And second, I believe your language is too technical for OP's current level.

Comment: @Dialecticus - I reworded the part about the requirement.

Answer (score -1):

```
Rectangle(double w= 1.0, double l= 1.0);
```

in the header file

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(double w, double l)
{
    if ( w> 0 && w < 20.0)
        width=w;
    else
        width=1.0;
    length= l > 0 && l < 20.0 ? l : 1.0;
}
```

in the cpp file

in main call it by using `Rectangle R(12,5);`

Comment: Provide a complete explanation, this is not an answer